# MobX - call method from another store

Tags: javascript, mobx

I have two MobX stores:

```
export default class AccountStore {
    accounts : Account[] = [];

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    loadAccounts = async () => {
        //call to loadOthers
    }
}
```

and

```
export default class OtherStore {
    others : Others[] = [];

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    loadOthers = async () => {...}
}
```

In my `AccountStore` class, in my `loadAccounts` function I want to make a call to `loadOthers` from the other `MobX` store. How can I make this call?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you initialize your stores. The most simple way is to have singleton stores, that way you can just import it directly.

Another way is you have some sort of root store, which initializes all other store, and pass itself to every store too, that way you have reference to the root store and to every other store from any store. Something like that:

```
class RootStore {
  constructor() {
    this.accountStore = new AccountStore(this)
    this.otherStore = new OtherStore(this)
  }
}


class AccountStore() {
  constructor(rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore.
  }

  loadAccounts = async () => {
    this.rootStore.otherStore.callOthers()
  }
}
```

Third way is just pass `OtherStore` instance to `loadAccounts` function. For example if you want to call `loadAccounts` when some React component mounts you can do that in `useEffect`, just get both store, and pass one to another:

```
export default class AccountStore {
  // ...

  loadAccounts = async (otherStore) => {
      // ...
      otherStore.loadOthers()
  }
}
```